# Create a new item and Update the same item using Sharepoint 2013 designer workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, list-view-threshold

Based on status change in List A, i'm trying to move the list item to a very large archived list(200,000 items)say List B. I'm using Create new Item and Update same item based on a look up value. I have to copy 70 columns from List A to List B. Create New item allows to create 55 columns one at a time so i'm using update action to update rest 15 cols. Update is failing with the error message that this action is prohibited because of list threshold. Any suggestion how can this be done?
Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an index setup on the large list? This would be the recommended first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the update step in "App Step". This will allow to overcome threshold issue.

Comment: App Step is grayed out. I'm not sure if this works for List workflow. But the suggestion by billfredtom worked. I indexed the column and its updating.

Comment: Ok great. Just for your information, to add app step you must turn on the Site Feature "Workflow can use app permissions" in the Site Settings > Manage site features.